# My UITableViewCell containing a UIScrollView stopped scrolling vertically in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios9

I just noticed a behavior change that seems related to migrating to iOS 9.

I have a `UITableView`. In the first `UITableViewCell` I have a `UIScrollView` that I use to page through images. It should only scroll **left<-->right**. Finger dragging up and down should drag the `UITableView` up and down. Up until iOS 9 it did do that beautifully...  Now when I compile for iOS9 devices or simulator I can still scroll the images **left<-->right** but the table no longer scrolls up and down. Those touches just get sucked into the abyss.

Let me add that when I compile from Xcode 7 to my device running iOS 8.4 it still behaves as intended. Scrolls up and down when dragging in the embedded `UIScrollView`.

Furthermore, when I download my last released version (compiled on previously released Xcode for iOS 8.1 target I get the expected behavior on the iOS 9 phone.

Additional wrinkle of weirdness: if (back in xcode7 compiling live to iOS9 device again) I start scrolling vertically from one of the other cells and the table is still gliding to a stop THEN I CAN drag up and down from the `UIScrollView`. What the heck?

Anything obvious jump out here?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in iOS 9 changes with respect to self's frame, apparently. I had to change this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*self.pageImages.count, self.frame.size.width);
```

to this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*self.pageImages.count, self.window.frame.size.width);
```

See that reference to window in the final version? Second time that bit me. :)